# Greenplum Security: How do i setup Password-less Login: Windows (via Putty) to Linux(greenplum master machine-centos6.5) in gpdb cluster

Tags: linux, ssh, greenplum, hawq

We have small array of GPDB Cluster. We have recently upgraded the GPDB and configured the GCC web portal. In that, we noticed  Our machines  is still showing password at the time of SSH .

We tried following Document commands on greenplum machine:

http://www.servermom.org/passwordless-ssh-login/1608/

Unable to get passwordless SSH  at root user from windows to linux machine.

Though,We have ability to do passwordless SSH from Linux to linux  machine in gpdb cluster.

Trying to secure shell for greenplum  from windows to linux: 
Password-less Login: Windows (via Putty) to Linux(greenplum)

Is there any standard way or steps to perform Login via SSH without prompt of password. and from which user should we need to perform all these activities.

Any Help on it  would be much appreciated ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for asking this question, I never thought of this..
Here is what I did and It worked for me.

- Open `Putty Key Generator`
- Generated Key and copy it into .ssh/authorized_keys (Make sure you are copying complete key)
- `chmod -R 700 .ssh/`

[image]

- Save public and private keys (See Image)

[image: Save keys]

- Now open putty and provide `user@hostname`
- In Category goto `Connection > SSH > Auth` and load private key `(.ppk file)` you have saved from `Putty Key Generator`

[image]
 - Save the session and open

[image]

Comment: We are Doing the  same steps  but getting  prompt of  password  after  these steps

Comment: DO  we need to this autherized key for all  host. or each time we have to proceed with  each steps . Let's say we have 5 machine in a cluster . so we need to conduct 5 times these mentioned steps ?

Comment: No... There is no need to copy key in all hosts... If possible please give me ```/etc/ssh/sshd_config```

Comment: means  only i have to  look for /etc/ssh/sshd_config .Please can you  what should i  change in it.

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/NHJbXWtrxiE7DjLHek7wwF  here is content of  sshd_config  files.

Comment: If you are trying for root user add this ```PermitRootLogin yes``` line in ```sshd_config```

or check this ```cat /var/log/secure | grep -i error```

Comment: [root@mdw ssh]# cat /var/log/secure | grep -i error
[root@mdw ssh]#

Comment: here is Log for   /var/log/secure  http://paste.ofcode.org/9XeEjBPUafjskwUeGbYRdt

Comment: ```/etc/pam.d/sshd``` & ```/etc/pam.d/system-auth``` ?

Comment: Thanks we have configured passwordless SSH FOR windows to linux.

Comment: @vickps Please mention what fixed your issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113750/discussion-between-vickps-and-gpdude).

Answer (score 1):

A couple things to watch out for:

`~gpadmin/.ssh` directory and `~gpadmin/.ssh/authorized_keys` should have 700 and 600 permissions, respectively:

```
$ ls -lda ~gpadmin/.ssh
drwx------  15 gpadmin  gpadmin  510 May 27 11:43 /home/gpadmin/.ssh

$ ls -l ~gpadmin/.ssh/authorized_keys
-rw-------  1 gpadmin  gpadmin  4496 Dec  2 11:12 /home/gpadmin/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

When you connect with Putty, try enabling verbose output to be sure it is using the matching private key for the public key you've added to the Greenplum `authorized_keys` file.

You can also look in the `/var/log/secure` log file to see what the Greenplum server's SSHD process is doing for more clues.

Comment: We have been confirmed that   respective permission of .ssh folder and its files. it seems ok. when connection with putty it  still prompt for password  on ssh